# Redirect from website to mobile phone app

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

Someone asked me to create a script that redirect a **mobile** user directly to the phone app with a phonenumber inserted. Instead of viewing the webpage.

Somehow my script only works on a on-click event and not on the page load event.

I tried to open the phone app with window.open('tel:+612345678') and window.location.href = 'tel:+612345678'; But without succes my latest attempt is to create a link element dynamically and then call window.location.href=document.getElementById('redirectToPhoneElement').href;
but also without succes.

```js
(function(){
var tel = "tel:+612345678"; // hier telefoonnummer invullen zonder +

function detectmob() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
        var dRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        var width = screen.width * dRatio;
        var height = screen.height * dRatio;
        if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){
         // check landscape max width
            if(height / dRatio <= 480){
                //document.writeln('ls mobile');
                GoToPhone();
            }
        } else {
            if(width / dRatio <= 480){
                //document.writeln('p mobile');
                GoToPhone();
            }
        // check potrait width
        }
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i))
    {
        GoToPhone();
    }
}

function GoToPhone(){
    var telLink = document.createElement("a");
    var telText = document.createTextNode("call");
    telLink.appendChild(telText);
    telLink.href=tel;
    telLink.id="redirectToPhoneElement";
    document.body.append(telLink);

    window.location.href=document.getElementById('redirectToPhoneElement').href;

}
detectmob();
})();
```

How can I make the redirect work automatically?

Greets

Comment: can you wait for the page to be fully loaded first before calling the `detecmob` (`DOMContentLoaded` if i'm not wrong)? i suspect your problem lies on the script runs before the `href` element rendered..

Comment: (function(){}(); is an anonymous function and can be used as shorthand for this so the page is fully loaded. I have logged the href wich returns the phone number

Comment: I don't think you should force user to use the mobile app when they visit your website. We made that mistake in our own company and google punish us for it by hiding us in the search results. ppl will then use "force desktop" mode then...

Answer (score 0):

You can call function on window loaded with `href="tel: 3281769362"`, it also works on mobile phone

```js
function call() {
  document.getElementById("call").click();
}
window.onload = call;
```

```html
<a id="call" href="tel:123-456-7890">Wait</a>
```

Comment: it doesn't work on my device.
On my laptop it works fine but on my android device not

Comment: ```function rtCall(){
 document.getElementById("redirectToPhoneElement").click();
}
window.onload = rtCall; ```

Comment: Why did you send this ?

Comment: cause I thought maybe I typed a typo.

when I change "tel:123-456-7890" to an other page like "test.html" the redirect works fine. Maybe it's my phone or settings?

Comment: Okay... You shouldn't force people to call on page load, you should let them call with their own consent, just a friendly advice